# Image source is not found in my JSP page. Getting 404 page not found in browser console

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets

I know there is some mistake I'm making but I can't figure out what it is. Please help me out.

This is my project folder structure.

[image: This is my project folder structure]

I tried below -

1. `background="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/backgroundImage.jpg"`
2. `background="images/backgroundImage.jpg"` for body tag.
3. I tried that css url also.

I'm getting same error in my browser console.
[image: Browser console error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the string "localhost:/1" in the console? Try manually editing the url path in your console, until you find the image. Then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man I will suggest you to create a folder `resources` under `webcontent`. Put all your images inside there. 
Then in your jsp page map that image like

```
<img src="/resources/backgroundImage.jpg"" alt="View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

Comment: Thanks. The images folder should not be under META-INF. Now I put it under WebContent and it's working fine.